# Check an Array for latest timestamp

Tags: python-2.7

```
[["a","some_variable_data","01.02.2021"]
["a","some_variable_data","01.03.2021"]
["a","some_variable_data","01.04.2021"]
["a","some_variable_data","11.02.2021"]
["b","some_variable_data","01.02.2020"]
["b","some_variable_data","01.03.2020"]
["b","some_variable_data","01.04.2020"]
["b","some_variable_data","11.02.2020"]]
```

i have to check the latest timestamp for each first array field and add this to the rows. so the result should look like:

```
 [["a","some_variable_data","01.02.2021"]
["a","some_variable_data","01.03.2021"]
["a","some_variable_data","01.04.2021","latest"]
["a","some_variable_data","11.02.2021"]
["b","some_variable_data","01.02.2020"]
["b","some_variable_data","01.03.2020"]
["b","some_variable_data","01.04.2020","latest"]
["b","some_variable_data","11.02.2020"]]
```

i need some help/hint how to realize this. can anybody help me? i have to use python 2.7

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if `sorted([ that array ])` works, but you can try that.

Lets say: `array = [ that bigger array you shared ]`.
We know the location of the dates: the 3rd element (index 2). It's also sorted on the first element of the list: "a" or "b"
A possible option is to split the array into two arrays: one starting with "a" and one with "b".

Next, you can sort on the `array_a[2]` element in the list. Depending on the date and month, you can see if it was before, or after.
At the end, you simply merge the big arrays together:
`print([1,2,3]+[4,5,6]) # [1,2,3,4,5,6]`

Answer (score 0):

```
def latest(n):
    n = list(filter(None, n)) #delete_empty
    n.sort(key = lambda date: datetime.strptime(date, '%d.%m.%Y')) #sort date
    n=n[::-1] #reverse list
    #print(n)
    latest=""
    for lp in n:
        latest=lp
        break
    return latest
```

found a way:

- build list for each first key and sort them as datetime, then pick latest and rebuild the initial list